# Save many-to-many related entities C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, many-to-many

Need to save Related Entities with a many-to-many relationship in the below case,

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
}

public class BookCategory
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

I have a book entity with the below code,

```
var book = _dbContext.Book
                .Include(b => b.BookCategory)
                .AsTracking()
                .FirstOrDefault(e => e.BookId == bookId);
```

Now I am making the following changes to `book` object,

```
book.Title = "New Title";
book.BookCategories = model.Categories.Select
                      (c => 
                           new BookCategories{
                           BookId = c.Id,
                           CategoryId = c.CategoryId
                      }).ToList();
```

Now I want to save this `book` entity object with all the newly added `BookCategories` Entities.
EX: In this case, `book` Entity will be updated and 2 new entries of `BookCategories` will be added to DB.

I tried with `_dbContext.SaveChanges()` but got the following exception of type `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException`,

```
Self referencing loop detected with type 'Entities.BookCategory'. 
Path 'Before.BookCategory[0].Category.BookCategory[0].Book.BookCategory'.
```

Please suggest the best code to save this DB records.

Comment: Have you tried `_dbContext.SaveChanges()`  ?  If book has been updated, EF will notice the changes and write them to the DB.

Comment: Yes, it gives me Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException type of exception with the following message.

Self referencing loop detected with type 'Entities.BookCategory'. 
Path 'Before.BookCategory[0].Category.BookCategory[0].Book.BookCategory'.

Comment: What has JSON serialisation got to do with EF?  I think you aren't showing the code with the problem.  Where is the serialisation bit? Have you got some value converters somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

After updating the book object, I would create a new list of objects, add them to the context, then save them.

```
book.Title = "New Title";
_dbContext.Update(book);

var bookCategories = model.Categories.Select
                  (c => 
                       new BookCategories{
                       BookId = c.Id,
                       CategoryId = c.CategoryId
                  }).ToList();

_dbContext.AddRange(bookCategories);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: There is no need for the `Update` or `AddRange`, the fact that you have changed `BookCategories` is detected by EF, and all the changes will be written automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is below only.

```
_dbContext.SaveChanges()
```

We do not require to use `Update`. I had another code issue with FK dependency.
The code is working now.

Thank you